# What happens when there are more than one @JmsListener in an application? (in terms of concurrency)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jms, ibm-mq

I am trying to consume messages from three IBM MQ queues using JMS.

So, there are three @JmsListener in my spring boot application.

I have a doubt about it, how will they behave if all consumer can consume from their respective queues.

- Will there be any concurrency?
- If not what is the best way to concurrently consume from queues as I can't afford the serial execution of the application.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the JmsListener annotation you can set the concurrency behavoir:

> concurrency
>
> public abstract String concurrency
>
> The concurrency limits for the listener, if any. Overrides the value
>   defined by the container factory used to create the listener
>   container. The concurrency limits can be a "lower-upper" String — for
>   example, "5-10" — or a simple upper limit String — for example, "10",
>   in which case the lower limit will be 1.
>
> Note that the underlying container may or may not support all
>   features. For instance, it may not be able to scale, in which case
>   only the upper limit is used.

Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/annotation/JmsListener.html#concurrency--

Each Listener runs in it's own Thread.

You can easily test this by printing the message received. This will output the Thread it runs in. For example:

```
2020-06-06 11:26:54.339  INFO 23404 --- [enerContainer-1] c.e.d.ShippingService                    : Hello World!
```

The thread name is [enerContainer-1]

Please read more in the documentation about Spring and JMS https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#jms-receiving

Comment: Doesn't this setting just mean how many message are sent to the onMessage method for a single queue?  I think the question is if there are 3 different listeners on 3 different queues are all three queues read concurrently or serially?  I think it is concurrently, but am not a Spring export.

Comment: Ah I understand. Each listener runs in its own thread. So yes it's concurrent

Comment: Thank you for confirming, and I'm sure you are much more of a spring expert than I am a "spring export" :).  Will you be updating your answer with those details?

Comment: Added the information how you can check if the Listener runs in a Thread

Comment: Thank you @SimonMartinelli for answering my query, your first answer (concurrency within the container) was also a great help.